# Imagemagick wand use of depth is not working like command line

Tags: python, linux, imagemagick, wand, color-depth

So I used to run imagemagick direct in a bash script like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert image.jpg -resize 1000x1000\! -depth 2 result.jpg
```

[image: result.jpg]

SO I decided to convert my script to python using wand!

```
from wand.image import Image
...
with Image(file=f) as img:
    img.transform(resize='1000x1000!') 
    img.depth = 2
    img.save(filename='result_py.jpg') 
f.close()
...
```

[image: result_py.jpg]

I've noticed that if I remove the "-depth 2" from the bash script, the result image will be exactly like the result from python, so what am I missing in the python program? Why does do the depth option in python is not working?

Comment: I tried your code with your first image as input and it produces the exact same image both with `convert` and `wand.image` - if you run `identify -verbose result.jpg`, however, it shows `Depth: 8-bit`...

Comment: Post your original image. What is your version of ImageMagick? What version of Wand? If not the latest versions try upgrading.

Comment: @MoRe, you can use the second image as original for testing.
the original (image.jpg) is a 25x25 size from the second one

Comment: @fmw42 origina(image.jpg),
http://www.upl.co/uploads/circuloas181536536659.jpg

Answer (score 1):

With Python's wand library, you want to use `wand.image.Image.quantize` method, and reduce the colors down to 4 (black/white + 2 colors).

```py
from wand.image import Image
...
with Image(file=f) as img:
    img.transform(resize='1000x1000!') 
    img.quantize(4,      # Number of colors
                 'gray', # Colorspace
                 0,      # Tree depth
                 False,  # Dither
                 False)  # Measure Error
    img.save(filename='result_py.jpg') 
f.close()
...
```

[image: quantize down to 4]

I believe the `quantize` method was added in version 0.4.2. Also note that wand currently supports ImageMagick-6, so it's possible that your system has both 6 & 7 installed.

Answer (score 0):

JPG does not support depth 2. It is alway output to depth 8 and the quantization will add more colors. Try your commands with PNG or GIF or TIFF with -depth 2. Does that work?

```
convert -size 256x256 gradient: -depth 2 grad_d2.jpg

  Depth: 8-bit
  Colors: 10
  Histogram:
     10752: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 gray(0)
       256: (  1,  1,  1) #010101 gray(1)
       512: ( 84, 84, 84) #545454 gray(84)
     20992: ( 85, 85, 85) #555555 gray(85)
       256: ( 86, 86, 86) #565656 gray(86)
       256: (169,169,169) #A9A9A9 gray(169)
     21248: (170,170,170) #AAAAAA gray(170)
       256: (171,171,171) #ABABAB gray(171)
       256: (254,254,254) #FEFEFE gray(254)
     10752: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF gray(255)


convert -size 256x256 gradient: -depth 2 grad_d2.png

  Depth: 8/2-bit
  Colors: 4
  Histogram:
     11008: (  0,  0,  0) #000000 gray(0)
     21760: ( 85, 85, 85) #555555 gray(85)
     21760: (170,170,170) #AAAAAA gray(170)
     11008: (255,255,255) #FFFFFF gray(255)
```

Perhaps Wand has a bug or you are using too old a version? The resulting images should look similar from JPG or PNG, but the JPG will just have more closely similar colors.

Comment: python -m wand.version
0.3.8

Version: ImageMagick 7.0.7-22 Q16 x86_64 2018-02-08

Comment: Wand is at 0.4.4. You might try upgrading. ImageMagick is at 7.0.8.11 Q16, but your version seems to be recent enough and works properly.  When I process  your image as jpg and png, they look similar. But the JPG has 103 colors and a 256 color colormap and depth 8. The PNG has 2 colors and 4 color colormap.

Comment: Ok, I updated to 0.4.4 and added 
img.format = 'png'
now its working like a charm

Comment: Does it work for jpg, now also? It should look similar, but just have more close colors from the jpg compression.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me in Wand. But I am not a Wand expert. I suggest you post this issue to the Wand developers.